# Why the Chomsky Hierarchy?

Tags: formal-languages, automata, chomsky-hierarchy

The hierarchy

$$\text{regular languages $\subset$ 
deterministic context-free languages $\subset$ 
context-free languages $\subset$ 
context-sensitive languages $\subset$ 
recursively enumerable languages}$$

has an 'extra level' with respect to the Chomsky Hierarchy.

***Why is the Chomsky hierarchy taught, as opposed to some other hierarchy?***

Answer (score 1):

It is an arbitrary choice, based on a judgement call of the instructor about which levels of the hierarchy are most useful to focus on.

I think one could make a good argument for focusing on the even simpler hierarchy

$$\text{regular languages} \subset \text{context-free languages} \subset \text{recursively enumerable languages},$$

as most automata theory courses focus primarily on those three categories.  Many of them devote considerably less time to context-sensitive languages and to deterministic context-free languages.

Generally, regular languages are considered valuable to study because they form the foundation of lexing (for compilers), for pattern-matching (for everyone who uses regexes), and for finite-state automata; and because they have an elegant theory that is is perhaps easiest to learn.

Generally, context-sensitive languages are considered valuable to study because they form the foundation for parsing.

Generally, recursively enumerable languages are considered valuable to study because they form the foundation for a study of decidability and computability.